# Which power did Eleven employ here?

Tags: stranger-things

In Season 4 of *Stranger Things*, after Vecna

> viciously attacks Max and leaves her dying, she suffers cardiac arrest.

Eleven, who is remotely viewing the situation at this point, does...something...to prevent this character from dying, at least until  medical help can arrive, but seems to be unable to do much to help them later on, even in person.

Was this a specialized application of her main telekinesis-related or electricity-related (making lights flicker and so forth) powers (e.g. she performed some sort of crude defibrillation or chest compression remotely), or was it some separate, heretofore unseen healing ability?

Comment: I don't think more than you say is known now. Heart started to beat... somehow.

Comment: I'd have to agree that specifics might be explained later on. For now, it's left up to us to infer based on the powers we've seen from her so far. Jumpstarting her heart seems the most plausible.